# Can I use a Wordpress plugin in a website which uses languages like PHP?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website which is written in PHP. I like to add a Wordpress plugin to the existing website. Can I use a Wordpress plugin in websites which doesn't use Wordpress? Is there any way for integrating a WP plugin in such sites?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so without having WordPress as the plugins are built to be used by WordPress. There may be libaries of code for the same plugin that are neutral though and not dependent on a particular platform.

Answer (score 0):

After Googling this, I'm going to stick my neck out and say no. Basically what I said in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

No.You cant use word press plugin in core PHP,because it uses word press's core functions from start to end.